# Change widget background color in Kivy

Tags: widget, kivy, android-widget, background-color, kivy-language

As the title suggests, I want to be able to change the background color of a gridlayout widget in Kivy

I'm using the following code:

```
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


Builder.load_string('''
#:import utils kivy.utils
<BlueGrid>:
    GridLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#39B3F2")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        rows: 1
        cols: 2
        pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
        size_hint: 1, 1
        Label:
            text: "First Label"
            id: Label_1
        Label:
            text: "Second Label"
            id: Label_2
''')

class BlueGrid(GridLayout):
    pass

runTouchApp(BlueGrid())
```

I am expecting a blue gridlayout where each column is completing filled by one label. Instead, I get 
the output below, where everything is concentrated in the bottom left corner:
[output gridlayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zyw4.png)

I have also tried running the "BlueGrid" class without the runTouchapp, with the same result:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return BlueGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
    print(kivy.__file__)
```

What am I missing? Why are the two labels and the Rectangle in the Gridlayout all positioned on top of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this, is that the default size of the `GridLayout` is not enough to display both of the labels.
Also the root layout of your app might be better to be a `FloatLayout` or a `BoxLayout`, so it can occupy all of the window.

So one solution would be to set `class BlueGrid(FloatLayout):`

Another solution would be to keep it as a `GridLayout` but set its child `GridLayout` to a bigger size like this:

```py
<BlueGrid>:
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: 300
```

Comment: yeah, I should have used a floatlayout this whole time :).. thanks for the tipp

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice the warning:

```
[WARNING] <__main__.BlueGrid object at 0x7f2d2a414e18> have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.
```

That is because you have defined `BlueGrid` as an extension of `GridLayout`, but did not specify `cols` or `rows` in your `kv` for `BlueGrid`. You can correct that by just adding a `cols` specification:

```
<BlueGrid>:
    cols: 1
```

But because `BlueGrid` is a `GridLayout`, do you really want another `GridLayout` inside it? Perhaps a better solution is:

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
<BlueGrid>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#39B3F2")
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    rows: 1
    cols: 2
    pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
    size_hint: 1, 1
    Label:
        text: "First Label"
        id: Label_1
    Label:
        text: "Second Label"
        id: Label_2
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your help. No, I did not notice that warning until you mentioned it. And I also wasnt aware I was defining a gridlayout inside another gridlayout.. So yeah, Your solution is exactly what i was looking for :)